# How to print only the Echo Output with PHP

Tags: php, printing, echo

I have created a form that is handled by some PHP and echoed so it can be printed by the user.  My problem is that when it prints it is printing everything. I would like to only print the text and not the print button or the url. I'll post the PHP code below.

```
    <?php

    $beq = $_REQUEST["beq"];
    $blq = $_REQUEST["blq"];
    $bwq = $_REQUEST["bwq"];

    if ($beq>0)
    {
        echo ("Berry (SPR0110) " .$beq);
    }

    if ($blq>0)
    {
        echo ("<br />Black (SPA0212) " .$blq);
    }

    echo '<br /><br /><a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>';

    ?>
```

Comment: Use css @media feature

Answer (score 4):

Quickest way:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
    .hide-on-print { display:none; }
}
</style>

<?
$beq = $_REQUEST["beq"];
$blq = $_REQUEST["blq"];
$bwq = $_REQUEST["bwq"];

    if ($beq>0)
    {
        echo ("Berry (SPR0110) " .$beq);
    }

    if ($blq>0)
    {
        echo ("<br />Black (SPA0212) " .$blq);
    }

    echo '<div class="hide-on-print"><br /><br /><a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

create a stylesheet with screen and print rules

[Good rules for setting up print css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401623/good-rules-for-setting-up-print-css)