# webpage print without the header and footer from the browser

Tags: web, printing

I have a webpage, and I am using JavaScript .print();. however, I don't want have the header and footer from the browser(date and url). I had some research from the internet, it is within the browser, are controlled at the operating system/printer driver level and are not controllable at the HTML/CSS/DOM level. so my question is, is there any other options to suppress this with coding? like generate a file first and then print it from the file?

Comment: Generating a PDF file for example

Comment: yes. something like it, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could generate a PDF of the content and then set it to be printed. That way you could avoid the header and footer to be printed.

Comment: thank you for the reply, it sounds like a solution, but how can I do it? a third party app?

Comment: You could use a server-side lib (depending on your server capabilities) to create a PDF version and then just show a link like
"<a href="javascript: w=window.open('http://examplesite.com/pdf-file.pdf'); w.print(); w.close(); ">​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​print</a>"

Comment: It is a SharePoint page and the content is dynamic, it is not easy to do in this case.

Comment: I have no exeprience in sharepoint, but I think that was an acceptable answer to your initial question. Please mark it as the answer if you agree. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look into a print.css file.  You can actually dictate what gets printed, and only what you want, in a hidden area.

As per this SO thread:  [Print.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401623/good-rules-for-setting-up-print-css)

Comment: it is not in the page code, it is the one from browser. how to set it from browser is here: http://lifehacker.com/5603815/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-url-and-other-text-when-i-print-from-web-pages

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old question, but I was able to print a webpage without having the URL and date-time (which the browser adds on its own) printed.

I just added `@page { margin: 0; }`. I tested this to work with Chrome 70 and Firefox 61.

Do remember to specify it in the print media in css by wrapping it in `@media all {<css contents here>}` or `@media print {<css contents here>}`. Alternatively, in html tag, `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="<css file url>">`